# Can I pass multiple callback function inside withSuccessHandler?

Tags: google-apps-script, callback, asynccallback, multiple-arguments

This is the code i am running

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateSearchDropDown).searchByVehicleNum();
});
```

now my question is ,
Can i pass 2 callback functions inside withSuccessHandler?

something like this

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function1,function2).scriptFunc();
```

BTW I tried that and its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function1,function2).scriptFunc();
```

#### To:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(sample).scriptFunc();

function sample(e) {
  function1(e);
  function2(e);
}
```

or

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {function1(e), function2(e)}).scriptFunc();
```

#### Reference:

- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))